# Why bullet point doesn't show on second column on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm wondering why this is happening, the bullet is displaying properly on Safari and Firefox but the bullet on the 2nd column doesn't appear on Chrome. The ul.ul2col > li display: inline-block is a hack that I found but it don't allow it to work properly on Chrome still.

```
<ul style="ul2col">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
<ul>
```

My CSS

```
.ul2col { column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2}
ul.ul2col > li { display: inline-block }
```

How it is on Safari and Firefox

[image: On Safari and Firefox]

How it is on Google Chrome

[image: On Chrome]

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @TheDictator Yes, I am using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `list-style-position: inside;` to `.ul2col li` class.

```css
.ul2col { 
  column-count: 2; 
  -webkit-column-count: 2; 
  -moz-column-count: 2;
}
.ul2col li{  
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul2col">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try and have a look at it.

Comment: @HELLOHK It's working in chrome. I have already checked in chrome.

Comment: @HELLOHK ,pls note that you can not give `style="ul2col" `. you can give either inline css in style tag or give class to ul tag. you can not define class name in style tag.

Comment: I'll try to give the class another see and see if that will work.

Comment: @HELLOHK , which version of chrome have you used...?

Comment: The latest version of Chrome. I changed the class name and managed to fixed it :)